# wamp webpage with a name

Tags: web-services, wamp, html, wampserver

I need to make my webpage visible to all the people in my domain. Looking around i have found that i can do multiple webpages using virtualhosts, and ok i have done it, BUT all the guides tell me that if i want to acces it using a name not a ip, i need to modify the host file, which it isnt good because there is over 100 computers here and i cant go 1 by 1 changing the file so people can access it using mypage.local (for example)...

i guided myself using this webpage: https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

so i would like to know if there is a way to make people type mypage.local and it would take them to an ip 192.168.0.X where the pc with wampserver is.

Comment: Do you have a DNS Server in your local network?

Comment: Not the best tutorial to follow, have a look at this one http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is quite common.

The ability to enter a sensible domain name i.e. `stackoverflow.com` is based on the fact that browsers and other tools know that when they see a domain name they must go and query a Domain Name Server (DNS) in order to convert the human memorable domain name to an IP Address.

Everything that happens from then on uses the ip address.

So the solution to your problem depends upon having a DNS server, that all your potential users have their PC's configured to use, that you can add your domain into.

If you do not have a local domain name server the only other option is to tell each potential user how to add your domain name and ip address to their `\windows\system\drivers\etc\hosts` file. This file is used to seed the Windows DNS Cache and to all intents and purpose works a bit like a personal DNS server.

Of course if you have to install a DNS Server, assuming you have the skills, you would still have to get each user to change their PC config to use your DNSServer instead of whatever they currently use.

There is a potential frig, so to speak, that might work for you. Apache uses the first Virtual Host defined in the httpd-vhost.conf file as the default website. So if you only have one site that you want to share, you can make that one he first Defined VHOST and then users can enter the ip address of the WAMPServer PC eg `192.168.0.2` and Apache should default them to your site. Its not a elegant solution, but it does make use of a known intentional feature of Apache when using Virtual Hosts.

Comment: thank you for your help, thats what i thought i had to do, but didnt want to do it lol. Now, if i have a DOMAIN, can i change the dns of all computers in the domain using Active Directory? or maybe the host file in all them? thaknks again

Comment: That sounds like another question, and I cannot help you with that one.